# Rails rendering - structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4 app. Users create profiles. My question is when another user clicks on someone else's profile, how do i make sure the profile page renders shows the profile for the first user.

For example, if the current_user clicks on a profile page, the view will render the user's name, where it should render the name of the user that created that profile.

Is there logic for how do to this that you could share?

I'm wondering if I need to make a 'creator' attribute in the profile, so that the fields are shown with the data populated by the creator of that profile.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user profile table should has a foreign key user_id. Using the ActiveRecord `belongs_to` association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you can access the creator name by `user_profile.user.name`